# How to think in Python after working in C++?

Tags: c++, python

I'm brand new to Python and trying to learn it by replicating the following C++ function into python

```
// determines which words in a vector consist of the same letters
// outputs the words with the same letters on the same line
void equivalentWords(vector <string> words, ofstream & outFile) {
    outFile << "Equivalent words\n";

    // checkedWord is parallel to the words vector. It is
    // used to make sure each word is only displayed once.
    vector <bool> checkedWord (words.size(), false);

    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        if (!checkedWord[i]){
            outFile << "  ";
            for(int j = i; j < words.size(); j++){
                if(equivalentWords(words[i], words[j], outFile)) {
                    outFile << words[j] << " ";
                    checkedWord[j] = true;
                }
            }
            outFile << "\n";    
        }   
    }
}
```

In my python code (below), rather than having a second vector, I have a list ("words") of lists of a string, a sorted list of the chars in the former string (because strings are immutable), and a bool (that tells if the word has been checked yet). However, I can't figure out how to change a value as you iterate through a list.

```
    for word, s_word, checked in words:
    if not checked:
        for word1, s_word1, checked1 in words:
            if s_word1 == s_word:
                checked1 = True # this doesn't work
                print word1,
        print ""
```

Any help on doing this or thinking more "Pythony" is appreciated.

Comment: First lesson, it's "Pythonic" or "Pythonically" :-)

Comment: I think Pythonesque is much nicer sounding than Pythony :)

Comment: The usual term is "pythonic".

Comment: To expand a bit on PTBNL's comment:  "Pythonic" is an adjective, so you'd want to use the adverb "Pythonically" here.

Comment: Some Pythontastic comments here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping things simple, this is O(N) complexity and should be sufficient if you don't have GBs of word data. Note that `set()` and `dict()` basically is a hashed index (free and builtin!).

```
index = {}
for word, s_word in words:
    index[s_word] = index.get(s_word, []) + [word]

for similar_words in index.values():
    print ' '.join(similar_words)
```

Don't know what you are using it for, but it might be of interest to you that in python 2.7 a **[Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)** class was introduced in the collections module.

If you really want to keep your algorithm and update a boolean list (which you don't because that algorithm would do inefficient double loops), you would do it like this:

```
checked = [False] * len(words)
for i, (word, word_s) in enumerate(words):
    if checked[i]:
       continue
    for j, (other, other_s) in enumerate(words[i:]):
        if word_s == other_s:
            print other,
            checked[i+j] = True
    print
```

Comment: Assuming every word is going to be in the set, every word is going to be printed.  Or am I missing something?  (On the first code sample.)

Comment: I think this code misses the intent of the original problem and is not in anyway more pythonic

Comment: fair enough, looking at the post again I agree that the output is not what was requested. Instead I focused on the stated question of how to deal with the 'checked' booleans.

Comment: index.setdefault(s_word, []).append(word) is necessary to make the first program O(N). Otherwise, the repeated construction of new lists makes it O(N^2) in the worst case.

Answer (score 3):

I generally like catchmeifyoutry's answer, but I would personally tighten it up a bit further as

```
for word in set(words):
    print word
```

***Edit***:  My answer is a shorter but functionally equivalent form of catchmeifyoutry's original, pre-edited answer.

Comment: note that this will eliminate order (which may or may not be acceptable)

Comment: @cobbal: exactly, which is way it did it my way. But I generally like you answer too, John Y ;)

Comment: oops, this also doesn't print the non-unique words, as dash-tom-bang indicated, as did my original code example :S

Comment: @cobbal and catchmeifyoutry:  To be perfectly honest, my answer literally was just a tighter but functionally equivalent form of the original answer posted by catchmeifyoutry (which has since been totally blown away by editing).  Any flaws in that original answer would naturally be in my answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you're looking for is Pythonic, here's a pythonic code sample for what you're tying to do, determine words that are equivalent, where equivalence is determined by having the same set of letters

```
import collections

def print_equivalent_words(words):
    eq_words = defaultdict(list)
    for word in words:
        eq_words["".join(sorted(set(word)))].append(word)

    for k,v in eq_words.items():
        print(v)
```

Comment: +1 for having correct output in 1 post ;). Using defaultdict for this is really nice too, but just note that it requires python >= v2.5.

Comment: Actually it took me 15 minutes in the Python REPL to get this right because my Python was so rusty :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best algorithm to solve this problem (it's O(N^2) instead of O(N)), but here's a pythonic version of it. The method I've used is to replace your array of bits with a set that contains words you've already seen.

```
checked = set()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word in checked:
        continue
    to_output = [word]
    for word2 in words[i + 1:]:
        if equivalentWords(word, word2):
            to_output.append(word2)
            checked.add(word2)
    print ' '.join(to_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `words` a list of objects:

```
class Word(object):
  def __init__(self, word, s_word, checked=False):
    self.word = word
    self.s_word = s_word
    self.checked = checked

 ....
    for word1 in words:
      if word1.s_word == word.s_word:
        word1.checked = True
        print word1.word
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment:

```
// determines which words in a vector consist of the same letters
// outputs the words with the same letters on the same line
```

I'm not quite sure that the original code works, and even if it does, I can't say I like it much. First of all, based on the loop nesting, it looks like the complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>). Second, I can't figure out what it's doing well enough to be sure it really does what's stated above (it uses a three-parameter overload of `equivalentWords`, which seems to be missing, which makes it hard to say though).

Some of the Python solutions are a lot shorter and simpler -- to the point that I feel reasonably certain they simply don't work. A couple seem to simply print out unique words, which (at least as I interpret it) is *not* the intent at all.

Here's a version in C++ that does what I interpret the requirements to be:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::string 
sort_word(std::string word) { 
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    return word;
}

namespace std { 
    std::ostream &
    operator<<(std::ostream &os, 
               std::pair<std::string, std::set<std::string> >const &words) 
    { 
        std::copy(words.second.begin(), words.second.end(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, "\t"));
        return os;
    }
}

void 
equivalentWords(std::vector<std::string> const &words, std::ostream &os) { 
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string> > word_list_t;
    word_list_t word_list;

    for (int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
        word_list[sort_word(words[i])].insert(words[i]);

    std::copy(word_list.begin(), word_list.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<word_list_t::value_type>(os, "\n"));
}

int 
main() { 
    std::vector<std::string> input;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::back_inserter(input));
    equivalentWords(input, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

I *think* using that as a starting point for a Python version is more likely to produce a clean, working result.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is pythonic, but I'm quite proud of it.

```
import itertools

for _, to_output in itertools.groupby(sorted(words, key=sorted), sorted):
    print ' '.join(to_output)
```